# How to group values from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples.

[(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(4,7),(7,9),(3,5),(5,6),(11,17)]

**The relation is**

If (1,2) belongs to a domain and (2,3) belongs to a domain then [1,2,3] belongs to same domain.

**Output should be**

{'c1': {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 9, 6}, 'c11' : {11, 17}}

I tired like this, but it fails for complex/big inputs (e.g. when I = 500)

Tuple is taken from stdin

```
N, I = input().strip().split()
N, I = [int(N), int(I)]

connections = {}

for i in range(I):
    l, m = input().strip().split()
    l, m = [int(l), int(m)]

    if(connections == {}):
        connections['c'+str(l)] = set([l, m])

    for key in list(connections):
        if l in connections[key] or m in connections[key]:
            connections[key].update([l, m])
            break
    else:
        connections['c'+str(l)] = set([l, m])

print(connections)
```

Comment: Basic graph theory: finding connected components of a graph. Also what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to implement a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). If so, a quick Google search will provide you with various implementations in Python.